# How to insert user data in mysql database using an AWS Cognito User Pool lambda Trigger

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, cpanel

I am trying to make it so that when a user signs up on my application and confirms their account, that it updates the user mysql database on cpanel. I found that you can use AWS AWS RDS to create a database instance, however it is pretty pricey to use.

Is there a cheaper alternative to insert rows in my remote database through an AWS lambda trigger.

Comment: You're speaking about 2 different things. RDS is a database infrastructure managed by AWS, while the DB you see in cpanel is a database hosted on your server. 
When you talk about your application, do you already have one, and where is your backend hosted ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use cognito lambda triggers to invoke lambda function.
Cognito lambda triggers support multiple events such as user sign-up and sign-in.

Since you want to trigger the lambda after the user successfully signs up, you can use the [Post confirmation Lambda trigger](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-post-confirmation.html)

```
Post confirmation Lambda trigger - Adds custom welcome messages or event logging for custom analytics
```

Similar to the example provided in the doc, we can do the same to insert user data into a database.

```js
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  console.log(event);

  if (event.request.userAttributes.email) {
    insertIntoDatabase(event.request.userAttributes.email, function (status) {
      // Return to Amazon Cognito
      callback(null, event);
    });
  } else {
    // Nothing to do, the user's email ID is unknown
    callback(null, event);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create lambda function in AWS which will act like api(web hook) for your application.